# Spock MissingMethodException

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I have something that looks like the similar specification:

```
def "my spec"(Record record) {
    given: 
        Something something = getSomething()
    and: 
        otherThing = getOtherThing()

    doFlow(something, record)
    if (record.someType = Types.SOME_SPECIFIC_TYPE) {
        doFlow(something, record)
    } 
}

def doFlow(Something something, Record record) {
    when:
         //code
    then:
         //asserts

    when:
         //code
    and: 
         //mode code
    then:
         //code
}
```

However, at runtime, I get: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method doFlow() is applicable for arguments Something, Record values: [given values]`.

Comment: Presumably this is followed by *The Search for Spock's Missing Method*. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "my flow" and "doFlow" are feature methods as they have blocks such as `given`, `when`, and `then`. It's Spock's responsibility to invoke feature methods, and one feature method cannot call another one. If `doFlow` is meant to be a helper method, it should use explicit `assert` statements, and shouldn't have any blocks.

PS: Feature methods can't declare method parameters unless they are data-driven (i.e. have a `where` block).

PPS: A feature method can't just have a `given`/`and` block. (You'll get a compile error for this.)

Comment: And isn't there some annotation that says Spock that this is just a simple method and not a feature method?

Comment: A simple method is one that doesn't have blocks and the features that come with them. The reason why the feature that you are asking for isn't supported is that it's not clear what it would mean to, say, call a method that has an `expect` block from another method's `when` block. Suddenly the `when` block would no longer fulfill its purpose of (only) exercising the code under test.